# Choose the template of UI-TAB

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I have to do some tabs with ui.bootstrap in a web application. I want to choose a template for each tab, but it doesn't work. Why? This the tabs.html:

```
<uib-tabset active="activeForm">
  <uib-tab index="0" heading="One" templateUrl="one.html"></uib-tab>
  <uib-tab index="1" heading="Two" templateUrl="two.html"></uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Both 'one.html' and 'two.html' are in the same directory of 'tabs.html'.
P.S. it doesn't give me a error, simply it doesn't show me the template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `template-url="one.html"`.

Comment: Then your template is not defined properly. Can you post the content of your tab template here?

Comment: Well it cannot work. There is no click handler, no styles, no any directives or bindings for the data. Take a look at the default template for reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/tabs/tab.html

Comment: Just to add to this, make sure you are using a recent version of angular-ui-bootstrap.  I was struggling with this very issue and I was using 1.1.1; looking at the changelog, the `template-url` attribute looks to have been added in version 1.2.0.